# How to show that $(L_n,F_n) < 3$ (Lucas numbers and Fibonacci numbers)

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

While following the proof that no Fibonacci number is a perfect square larger than 144 (https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html) I stumbled in proving two of the elementary facts about Lucas and Fibonacci numbers.

(Lucas numbers have the same rule as Fibonacci numbers except that instead of $\{0, 1\}$ the Lucas sequences starst with $\{2,1\}$. The formulas in closed form are 
$ F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[ \rho^n - (-\rho)^{-n}\right] $ and 
$ F_n =  \rho^n + (-\rho)^{-n} $.)

The two properties I got stuck on is are that for $m \in \Bbb{N}$ and $r \in \{1,2\}$,
$$(L_{3m},F_{3m}) = 2$$
$$(L_{3m+r},F_{3m+r}) = 1$$

It is easy to show that both $F_n$ and $L_n$ are even only if $n$ is a multiple of 3, but the properties imply there are no other common factors.

What I have tried is to write $
L_s = \frac{p}{q} F_s $, attempting to show that $q$ must be at least $F_s/2$. The starting point is to use the closed form expressions to get
$$
\sqrt{5} = \frac{p}{q} +\frac{2}{F_s}(-\rho)^{-s}$$
and use the fact that $(-\rho)^{-s}$ falls rapidly with increasing $s$ so that at some point $\frac{p}{q}$ is "too close" for a rational approximation to $\sqrt{5}$ if $q < \frac{2}{F_s}$. I would then say that for smaller $s$, the properties hold by inspection, and for larger $s$, the value of $q$ must be large enough that the gcd in question cannot exceed 2. But I can't quite get that line of reasoning to work as a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$ for all $n$. So 
$$(F_n,L_n)=(F_n,F_{n-1}+F_{n+1})=(F_n, F_n+2F_{n-1})=(F_n,2F_{n-1}) \leq 2(F_n,F_{n-1})=2 \, .$$

Comment: I like it.  Thanks. BTW, are you the Micah who is at IMSA?

Comment: You're quite welcome! I've never been anywhere near IMSA...